# Sidebar and pagination disappear with truncate_html in production

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, truncate

So I decided to use the truncate_html gem so that I can remove tags from my posts when I want to preview them. It worked beautifully in development mode, I installed it just like the documentation says https://github.com/ianwhite/truncate_html but for some reason when I push to production with heroku my sidebar and my pagination disappear. The more important thing in this is my pagination

I reference pagination in my view like this

<%= will_paginate @posts %>

I used the gem in the view like this

```
    <h9><%= truncate_html(post.body, :length => 300) %></h9>
```

Has anyone has this error before or have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

There ended up being some character in two posts that for some reason completely messed up the entire site. I noticed that the list stopped at those posts no matter how many things I paginated it with so I took the post and copied it, placed it in text mate then reposted it and had no problem. Everything seems to be fine now and I don't have any issues. Not really sure what the problem was but if anyone else faces a similar problem maybe this well help. Anyway who looked over my question thanks!